# Is there an equivalent of Python's difflib.SequenceMatcher for Scala

Tags: scala, text, nlp

Is there something that implements the `difflib.SequenceMatcher` in Scala?  I need to convert some of my production code from Python to Scala but do not want to use something that will change the previous output from SequenceMatcher.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching I couldn't find anything so I researched the SequenceMatcher and wrote it up.  It's actually quite simple in Scala.  Please feel free to use this or improve on it.

```
/**
* Class SequenceMatcher - A simplified implimetation of Python's SequenceMatcher
*                         Currently only supports strings and ratio()
* @version 0.1
* @param stringA - first string
* @param stringB - second string
*/
class SequenceMatcher(stringA: String, stringB: String) {
  /**
  * ratio()
  * @return Return a measure of the sequences’ similarity as a float in the range [0, 1]
  */
  def ratio(): Double = {
    (2.0 * numOfMatches()) / (stringA.length() + stringB.length())
  }
  /**
  * numOfMatches()
  * @return number of characters that match in the two strings
  */
  def numOfMatches(): Long = {
    stringA.intersect(stringB).length()
  }
}
```

Comment: The difflib sequencemather uses the sum of the lengths of all maching substrings instead of the intersection (with duplicates) of characters in the string. Difflib also seems to take the longest substring first, then applies the algoritm separately to the remaining left and right side substrings, for each input string.

This implementation is quite different.

Ex. "aaxaa", "aaaax", returns 5 in this implementation (I think) and 3 in difflib's implementation.